# Understanding Css Grouping

Tags: html, css

(This might be a beginner question so you are welcome to refer me to other docs or questions)

I am trying to create sub classes in css. I want a group of general buttons like btn.general.X `(btn general plain, btn general alert, btn general secondary)` and a group of sidebar buttons like btn.sidebar.X `(btn sidebar general, btn sidebar alert, btn sidebar secondary)`.

Is there a way to split the `.btn.general` class so that it is not applied to all the subclasses. My example here shows how I want to create two different groups of buttons, but currently any button that has the classes `btn` and `general` is getting the `.btn.general` styles. I don't want the `.btn.sidebar.general` to get the `.btn.general` styles.

I checked through what I know but I'm not sure how to fix this.

```css
.btn.general {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.btn.sidebar {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="btn general plain" (click)="Login()">Login</button>
    <button class="btn general plain" disabled>Toets Button</button>
    <br><br>

    <div style="background-color: rgb(196, 196, 196); width: 150px;">
      <button class="btn sidebar general">Dashboard</button>
      <button class="btn sidebar general">Global</button>
      <button class="btn sidebar general">System</button>
      <button class="btn sidebar general">Preferences</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

So after going through all the answers I believe that my approach is wrong. If you want .btn.general to not be applied to btn.sidebar.general then make the first one .btn-general, then add .btn-general.foo (.error/.plain), and with the sidebar do .btn-sidebar.foo (.error/.plain). Grouping CSS seems like a very debatable topic so just go with what works for you I guess.

This link from the comment below by @Paulie_D helps a lot: https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/

Comment: If you're going to apply the class `.btn` _only_ to `<button>` elements and you're going to apply the class `.btn` to _all_ `<button>` elements, I'm pretty sure that you don't need the `.btn` class.

Comment: I think you might need to research BEM/SMACSS or OOCSS conventions...it's ideal for this situation - https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/

Comment: @Rounin remember that I have stuff like `inp general` and `lbl general` also, so I need the `btn general` here, but you have a good point still...@Paulie_D Thanks for this answer! A lot of good info in that link

Answer (score 2):

Use `not` CSS selector.

[See this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp)

```css
.btn.general:not(.sidebar) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.btn.sidebar {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="btn general plain" (click)="Login()">Login</button>
    <button class="btn general plain" disabled>Toets Button</button>
    <br><br>

    <div style="background-color: rgb(196, 196, 196); width: 150px;">
      <button class="btn sidebar general">Dashboard</button>
      <button class="btn sidebar general">Global</button>
      <button class="btn sidebar general">System</button>
      <button class="btn sidebar general">Preferences</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see how this solves the problem here but in a program this wouldn't be very efficient would it? You would end up with a big list of not items?

Comment: If you feel its inefficient then you should conisder using different classes for the different types of buttons.

Comment: Ok so you believe this is definitely the only way around the problem? Kinda sucks but I understand

Comment: You can wait for a better answer, that does the same without adiing new css classes. But i doubt you will find any answers. Post here if you find a better solution, I would love to learn too :)

Comment: Will do! I will mark yours as answered if I don't get a better answer :) Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the **cascade** in the Cascading Style Sheet.

First, identify which styles are common to all buttons:

```
button {
[... Styles which apply to all buttons in the document... ]
}
```

Then, identify which styles apply only to a subset of buttons:

```
.container button {
[... Specific styles which only apply to buttons in .container ... ]
}
```

Then, identify which styles apply to an even more specific subset of buttons:

```
.container .sidebar button {
[... More specific styles which only apply to buttons in .container .sidebar... ]
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
button {
margin: 12px;
padding: 6px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.container button {
font-style: italic;
border: 2px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.container .sidebar button {
font-style: normal;
background-color: rgb(255, 127, 0);
}

main {
background-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);
}

.container {
background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}

.sidebar {
background-color: rgb(127, 127, 127);
}
```

```html
<main>
<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>

<div class="container">
<h2>Container</h2>
<button>Button 3</button>
<button>Button 4</button>

<div class="sidebar">
<h3>Sidebar</h3>
<button>Button 5</button>
<button>Button 6</button>
</div>

<button>Button 7</button>
<button>Button 8</button>
</div>
</main>

<p>All buttons have <strong>bold text</strong>.</p>
<p>All buttons in <code>.container</code> have a <span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">red border</span>.</p>
<p>All buttons in <code>.sidebar</code> have an <span style="color: rgb(255, 127, 0);">orange background</span>.</p>
<p><strong><em>But...</em></strong> note that the text in the <code>.sidebar buttons</code> is not <em>italic</em> because it has a more specific declaration than all other buttons in <code>.container</code>.</p>
```

---

## Clarification of CSS syntax

I think I understand the way you're looking at it now.

The first - very important thing you need to know - is that **CSS classes do not have spaces**.

When you see something like this:

```
class="button magical spell"
```

what you're looking at is a *space separated list* of classes. The element has the class `.button` applied to it, the class `.magical` applied to it and the class `.spell` applied to it.

If, elsewhere, you this:

```
class="button magical wand"
```

***that*** element has the class `.button` applied to it, the class `.magical` applied to it and the class `.wand` applied to it.

That is to say, ***both*** elements have the classes `.button` and `.magical` applied to them.

Comment: This works but a solution where you need to put divs around everything is not really clean. So if I have 8 different buttons then I need to put 8 divs around them all. That will be some ugly html for just 8 buttons

Comment: Yes, I agree - the example above is just an example to show specificity and the cascade. It would never be necessary to give different buttons different parents just to change their styles. But you do (always) need to apply the more general style declarations first and the most specific style declarations last.

Comment: Thank you for your answer though. I did learn a new way of thinking from this

Comment: Please indent your html code (especially the divs) to make it more readable

Comment: Yes I understand that my code is not correct but that is why I am asking the question

Comment: I've added an update to my answer above. If I understand correctly, it was unclear that when an element has a class attribute and a list of words with spaces inbetween, you're not looking at a class - you're looking at a ***list*** of classes.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to use attribute selectors in css. It is common to use attribute selectors in case of elements like input - `input[type='text']`. You may try the same method here also. Please check the below example.

```css
button[class='btn general']{
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn general">Login</button>
<button class="btn general sidebar">Toets Button</button>
```

Comment: But this defeats the purpose of class groups, because you might as well just create unique classes for everything then. The idea is to make one `btn` class that has most of the button styling, and then add onto that with specifics like `btn alert` (red outline) or `btn primary` (a bit bigger) etc.

Comment: From your question what I understand as your primary requirement is "I don't want the .btn.sidebar.general to get the .btn.general styles." The attribute selector support it perfectly. I cant understand what you mean by "But this defeats the purpose of class groups". Could you please make it clear?

Comment: How is this different than just creating a `btn general {...}` class? That is my point

Comment: .btn.general will be effecting all elements with class names 'btn' + 'general' + anything... This attribute selector will be applied for the exact same attribute value only.